# Iinput information into a command prompt in python?

Tags: python, cmd

I wanted to type this into a command prompt in windows:
net users Administrator *
And it returns type a password in the cmd
I then want to type a password for eg:"pass"
Then type it again after enter is pressed.
How would i go about this? os.system() does not work. It goes to a new cmd each time.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html), you can redirect input and output of the process you created.